# Rounded corners on a navigation bar (HTML)

Tags: html, css

```css
div {
  width: 1310px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #212F3D;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav-centered" id="myTopnav">
  <a style="font-family:Verdana; color:White; font-size: 20px; display:inline; padding: 10px 50px; " href="01.HTML" class="active">Home</a>
  <a style="font-family:Verdana; color:White; font-size: 20px;  display:inline; padding: 10px 50px; " href="02.HTML">HTML</a>


</div>
```

I am doing a html project for school and I want to round the corners of my top navigation bar. I have a code but Im not certain that I have given the right part of my code.If I havent just tell me and I will edit It correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and you're done...

```
div {
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```css
div{
    width: 1310px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0; 
    background-color: #212F3D;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav-centered"id="myTopnav">
  <a style="font-family:Verdana; color:White; font-size: 20px; display:inline; padding: 10px 50px; "href="01.HTML" class="active">Home</a>
  <a style="font-family:Verdana; color:White; font-size: 20px;  display:inline; padding: 10px 50px; "href="02.HTML">HTML</a>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `border-radius` to round the edges of the navigation bar. You can also target each individual corner by:

```
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
```

Feel free to play with the values.
Here is your code edited https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWTO4Y7J67ZA

Some suggestions: you should target the top navigation bar by class or id. I suggest you do it by class reference. Also avoid as much as possible using inline styles, as you will have to write the code for so many times.

Answer (score 0):

This one will let you round a specific corner with a specific value.

```css
div{
    width: 1310px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0; 
    background-color: #212F3D;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

div {
//you can manipulate which side to round and which not
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav-centered" id="myTopnav">
  <a style="font-family:Verdana; color:White; font-size: 20px; display:inline; padding: 10px 50px; " href="01.HTML" class="active">Home</a>
  <a style="font-family:Verdana; color:White; font-size: 20px;  display:inline; padding: 10px 50px; " href="02.HTML">HTML</a>


</div>
```